# Question about React scroll down(anchor?)

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, anchor, styled-components

I'm JS newbie making a website :)

When I scroll down from main page,
I want to make it move to each component(Comp1,Comp2..) right away.
But I don't know what to do..
Can you tell me what to look for?

I wrote the react code as below.

```
import React from 'react'
import {Header} from 'components/Header'
import {Title} from 'style/CommonStyle';

const Comp1 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Title>Title of Comp1</Title>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
const Comp2 = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Title>Title of Comp1</Title>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}

const MainPage = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Comp1 />
      <Comp2 />
    </div>
  )
}

export default MainPage
```

Comment: So basically you are saying you need to scroll comp1 and comp2 even if the user scroll slightly? if that's the case you need to listen to window scroll event and either calculate the height or the comp1 and comp2 and scroll that amount or have a div after comp2 and givet the scroll amount the offset of that div.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Can I ask one more thing?

Using window.scrollTo, When I scroll down to a specific position,
it goes to top of Comp1. But When scroll from 
bottom to top, it also goes to comp1 too..